# ViewBag in View without @

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't get why we sometimes use ViewBag without reference (I mean @) to Controller in View, e.g.:

```
@{
    string urlFilter = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new
    {
        CustID = ViewBag.custid,
        Errors = ViewBag.errors
    });}
```

It looks like a part of c# code in view. I know that razor synthax allow us to inject c# code into View but don't understand what's the point of using ViewBag without @ in View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is because it is within the scope of a C# code block (`@{ ... }`) and not in the HTML markup.

If however, you were trying to reference the ViewBag inline in an HTML block you would need to prefix it with `@` to make sure it was processed by the Razor engine.

for example:

```html
<p>@ViewBag.Name</p>
```

`ViewBag` is a dynamic property on the `WebPageView` from which the view is derived.

You can learn about the Razor syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Comment: Ok so instead of creating ViewBag in Controller I can create it in View and it works the same as if I created ViewBag in Controller? I think I still don't get why we inject this kind of code (ViewBag.custid etc.) in View instead of Controller

Comment: @Muska typically you would set ViewBag values in the Controller and then reference them in the view. You do not have to create the ViewBag yourself. With the MVC framework the `ViewBag` you can reference in the controller and set values on will be the same as what you can reference from the Razor code blocks for a view being rendered as a result from that controller.